# Is there a limit to Batman's "power" of prep time?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

The common meme I have seen is that Batman, if given sufficient prep time, can defeat anyone in the DC Universe (or any universe, depending who you ask). Is this actually true in the current continuity, or is there a limit?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a limit.

The original Injustice saga starts as comics and ends as the Xbox/Playstation/PC game by the same name, as one single continuity. In the story, some characters from DC are taken from one universe to another, where alternate versions of them already exist.

This eventually leads Batman into a fight against Batman.

[image: Bat on bat action]

This is not two human players fighting each other, this is part of the story mode that you have to go through in single player.

Batman had been preparing for decades to fight not only against his enemies, but against every member of the Justice League as well. He prepared even to fight against himself, but in the end he got his own bat-keister handed to him on a plate. So Batman cannot defeat Batman.

On a more serious tone now, he had also been planning on how to defeat Superman for decades as well. He failed hard - and multiple times in a row - in that storyline. In the end it wasn't even him who did it. He has defeated Superman with less prep time in other stories, but Injustice shows that is not a constant.

Comment: The questions asks "in the current continuity". I don't think an Injustice story would suffice.

Comment: @TheIronCheek - As noted in the question, characters from what at least appears to be the mainstream DCU get pulled into the "Injustice" universe - that's the "other" Batman mentioned.